# Problem with a test while declaring a method in c++

Tags: c++, testing

I have a problem with the result of this test, with `Forme::prochainId()` :

```
TEST_CASE("Compteur", "[Forme]") {
   // Pour être correct, ce test doit etre le premier sur Forme
   REQUIRE(0 == Forme::prochainId());
   Forme f1;
   REQUIRE(0 == f1.getId());
   REQUIRE(1 ==  Forme::prochainId());  
   // Verification que la valeur n'est pas decrementee accidentellement.
   Forme *p = new Forme;
   REQUIRE(1 == p->getId());
   delete p;
   REQUIRE(2 == Forme::prochainId());   
}
```

This is the class Form and inside you can take a look at the prochainId() method:

```
#include "Forme.hpp"

int Forme::id = -1;

Forme::Forme(){

    id = id + 1;
    std::cout<<"COUCOU, je suis le constructeur de la classe Forme"<<std::endl;

}

Forme::Forme(Point p , COULEURS c){

    point = p;
    couleur = c;

}

 Point & Forme::getPoint() {

    return point;

}

COULEURS & Forme::getCouleur(){

    return couleur;
}

void Forme::setCouleur(COULEURS c){

    couleur = c;
}

void Forme::setX(int x){

    point.setX(x);

}

void Forme::setY(int y){

    point.setY(y);

}

int& Forme::prochainId(){
    id = id + 1;
    return id;

}


int& Forme::getId(){

    return id;

}
```

The erros is as in the picture : [image]

How should I declare the prochainId() method so the test can work?

Thank you!

Comment: Declare the function as `static`?

Comment: Please always copy-paste code and error messages as plain text into your question. Don't post text in images.

Comment: We don't know what the method (or the class itself) is suppose to do. But it seems that `id` is `static` and `prochainId` seems to only access this `static` member. Why then is it not itself declared `static`? You cannot call a non-static member functions with the syntax you are using. A non-static member must be called with an instance of the class, as you do e.g. in `p->getId()`. Please edit your question with a full [repro] and explain what you intend `REQUIRE(0 == Forme::prochainId());` etc. to do.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest declaring the function like this:

```
class Forme {

    static int prochainId();
};
```

There is another problem with your code.  It seems that you want `prochainId()` to return a distinct, incremented ID number for each object you instantiate.

You almost certainly want to add a *non-static* data member to `Forme` containing the ID for *each object (instance)*.  This way, each instance will "remember" its ID number, which will be fixed, even after other `Forme` objects are instantiated.

I've sketched this in the code below.

```
class Forme {
    static int id;     
    const int m_id_number;   // Non-static member, constant over the lifetime of each instance.

public:
    static int prochainId();

    Forme() : m_id_number{++id} {}
    // Use C++11 constructor delegation to invoke other constructor.
    Forme(Point p , COULEURS c) : Forme{} { ... };

    int getID() const { return m_id_number; }
};
```